# Robot framework loop verification sort

Tags: selenium, for-loop, automation, robotframework

I can't seem to do a loop to check if my element 1 is less than my element 2. In the xpath I put the variable i so that the robot goes to the next line when the condition element1 <element2. I'm doing a for loop because there are a lot of lines ... here is the code and thanks a lot

```
  [Arguments]  ${premiere_cellule}
  ${startValue}=    Set Variable   ${debut}
  ${endvalue}=      Set Variable   ${fin}
  ${step}=          Set Variable   ${pas}

  FOR    ${i}    IN    ${startvalue}    ${endvalue}    step=${step}
    ${Val1}=    Get Variable Value    ${premiere_cellule}
    FOR    ${i}+1    IN   ${startvalue}    ${endvalue}    step=${step}
       ${Val2}=    Get Variable Value   ${premiere_cellule}

       Run Keyword If    "${Val1}">="${Val2}"     Continue For Loop
       Exit For Loop If    "${Val1}"<="${Val2}"
  END
```

Comment: I think firstly you have to sort out your iteration logic. Robot framework do not support nested for loop and you have to make the inner for loop as a callable keyword. http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#nested-for-loops

Comment: Ty , do you have suggestions for my code ?

Comment: I'm not 100% but isn't val1 and val2 always holding identical value? They're both storing value of ${premiere_cellule} which as far as I can see isn't changed in the FOR loops